# Issue installing libxml2-python under OSX 10.9 (Mavericks) - incomplete definition of type 'struct _xmlBuf'

Tags: python, libxml2, osx-mavericks

I have a OSX 10.9 (Mavericks) installation.

I've installed Homebrew, and Python 2.7.6 and 3.3.3 as well as libxml2 2.9.1 through that (Homebrew).

I've also installed pip, and virtualenv.

I've created a new virtualenv, and I'm attempting to install libxml2-python, and I'm getting a C compilation error

```
  libxml.c:2548:28: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct _xmlBuf'
                buf->buffer->content = NULL;
```

Full gist is here:

https://gist.github.com/victorhooi/7761499

Any thoughts on what might be going on?

Cheers,
Victor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://mail.gnome.org/archives/xml/2012-August/msg00005.html

This probably explains...there was an API change in libxml2 and libxml2-python is quite old and outdated.